# Error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

compiler error :[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
could someone please help me , and tell me why my programme is giving me this error ?

the faulty code :

```
cout<<"Mode score: "<<printModeValues(scorePtr,size,modeFrequency(scorePtr,size));
```

my code:
Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "processScores.h"

int main()  {
    int * scorePtr;
    string * namePtr, scoresFileName;

    cout<<"Enter the file name: ";
    cin>>scoresFileName;

    unsigned size=getRecordsNumber(scoresFileName);
    scorePtr = new int[size];
    namePtr = new string[size];

    readRecords(scorePtr,namePtr,scoresFileName);
    sort(scorePtr,namePtr,size);

    cout<<"The records in ascending order of surnames are: \n";
    cout<<"Name          Score\n";
    cout<<"---------------------"<<endl;
    printScores(scorePtr,namePtr,size);

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Highest score: "<<highest(scorePtr,size)<<"\t";
    printFoundNames(scorePtr,namePtr,size,highest(scorePtr,size));
    cout<<"Lowest score: "<<lowest(scorePtr,size)<<"\t";    
    printFoundNames(scorePtr,namePtr,size,lowest(scorePtr,size));
    cout<<"Mean score: "<<mean(scorePtr,size)<<endl;
    cout<<"Mode score: "<<printModeValues(scorePtr,size,modeFrequency(scorePtr,size));
    cout<<"Modal value occurrences is "<<modeFrequency(scorePtr,size)<<" time\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"Median score: "<<median(scorePtr,size)<<endl; 
    delete [] scorePtr;
    delete [] namePtr;
}
```

the header file:

```
void printModeValues(const int *, size_t, int[]);
```

function prototype:

```
//**** MODE FREQUENCY ****
int modeFrequency(const int * scores, size_t size)
{
    int y[size] , modes[size];//Sets all arrays equal to 0
    int i,j,k,m,a,cnt,count=0,max=0,no_mode=0,mode_cnt=0;
    double num;

    for(k=0; k<size; k++)//Loop to count an array from left to right
    {
        cnt=0;
        num=scores[k];//Num will equal the value of array x[k]

        for(i=k; i<size; i++)//Nested loop to search for a value equal to x[k]
        {
            if(num==scores[i])
                 cnt++;//if a number is found that is equal to x[k] count will go up by one

        }

        y[k]=cnt;//The array y[k] is initialized the value of whatever count is after the nested loop

        if(cnt>=2)//If cnt is greater or equal to two then there must be atleast one mode, so no_mode goes up by one
        {
            no_mode++;
        }
    }

if(no_mode==0)//after the for loops have excuted and still no_mode hasn't been incremented, there mustn't be a mode
{
    //Print there in no mode and return control to main
    modes[1]=-1;
   // return modes;
}
    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
//A loop to find the highest number in the array
    {   
        if(y[j]>max)
        max=y[j];
    }
 for(m=0; m<size; m++)//This loop finds how many modes there are in the data set
{
    //If the max is equal to y[m] then that is a mode and mode_cnt is incremeted by one
    if(max==y[m])
        mode_cnt++;
}
//cout<<"This data set has "<<mode_cnt<<" mode(s)"<<endl;//Prints out how many modes there are
    for(m=0; m<size; m++)
    {
        if(max==y[m])//If max is equal to y[m] then the same sub set of array x[] is the actual mode
        {

            cout<<"The value "<<scores[m]<<" appeared "<<y[m]<<" times in the data set\n"<<endl;
            modes[count]=scores[m];
            count++;
        }
    }
return *modes;
}
//=====================================================================================
//**** PRINT MODE VALUE ****
void printModeValues(const int *scores, size_t size, int *mostAppearance)
{
    if (mostAppearance[0]== -1)
    {
        cout<<"-1 Modal value occurance is one time "<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int a=0 ; a< sizeof(mostAppearance); a++)
        {
            cout<<mostAppearance[a]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass a pointer, when only a value would be sufficient?

Comment: `modeFrequency` returns int but you are passing it to a function which should give an array! hence that error is given, I think you are giving the parameters in a wrong order

Answer (score 1):

Function `printModeValues` is declared the following way

```
void printModeValues(const int *, size_t, int[]);
```

As you see its third parameter is declared like `int[]` that is adjusted to `int *`

In this statement

```
cout<<"Mode score: "<<printModeValues(scorePtr,size,modeFrequency(scorePtr,size));
```

you call the function like

```
printModeValues(scorePtr,size,modeFrequency(scorePtr,size))
```

that is it uses as the third argument the value returned by function `modeFrequency`.

However this function has return type `int` instead of `int *` that is exprected by function `printModeValues` for its third parameter

```
int modeFrequency(const int * scores, size_t size);
^^^^
```

This is the reason for the error.

There are other errors in your program. For example in this function

```
void printModeValues(const int *scores, size_t size, int *mostAppearance)
{
    if (mostAppearance[0]== -1)
    {
        cout<<"-1 Modal value occurance is one time "<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int a=0 ; a< sizeof(mostAppearance); a++)
        {
            cout<<mostAppearance[a]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl; 
    }
}
```

the condition in this loop statement

```
        for (int a=0 ; a< sizeof(mostAppearance); a++)
```

does not make sense because operator `sizeof(mostAppearance)` yields the size of the pointer itself (usually 4  or 8 bytes). It is not the same as the number of elements in the array the first element of which is pointed to by this pointer.

It seems you was going to return a pointer from function `modeFrequency` that is you wanted to declare the function like

```
int * modeFrequency(const int * scores, size_t size);
```

and was going to return the pointer to the first element of array `modes`

```
int * modeFrequency(const int * scores, size_t size)
{
    int y[size] , modes[size];//

    //...

    return modes;
}
```

However even in this case the function will be invalid because it returns pointer to a local object of the function because array `modes` is a local  array. Moreover the C++ Standard does not allow to use variable length arrays. So this declaration

```
    int y[size] , modes[size];//
```

is not C++ compliant.

I would advice to use standard class `std::vector` instead of arrays in your program. Or you have to allocate arrays dynamically yourself.

Answer (score 0):

modeFrequency is returning int

```
int modeFrequency(const int * scores, size_t size)
```

but your printModeValues expecting an integer array.

```
void printModeValues(const int *, size_t, int[]);
```